# Average certain cells based on criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, average, criteria

[my excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWb91.png)

Basically I want to lump all strikes together by certain delta ranges and average them. I am trying to do this in the V5:X19 area.

I want to average all values in column G based of what is in column C given the same row

So in cell X6 I would like the formula to say "Average of all strikes widths(column G) in-between -3 and -1.1." and for it to copy down to average all widths with delta(column C) between -1.1 and -0.55, -0.55 and -0.25, ect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: take a look at the averageif function to and if it is available on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(untested) in cell X6.

`=averageifs(G:G,C:C,">="&V6,C:C,"<"&V7)`

Comment: could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002934/average-values-of-1-column-based-of-criteria-in-separate-column

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,,">="&V6,C:C,"<"&W6)/COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&V6,C:C,"<"&W6)
```

[image]

Comment: that is close except my criteria range is based off a different column than what I want to average together. I want to average all values in column G based of what is in column C given the same row.

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002934/average-values-of-1-column-based-of-criteria-in-separate-column